# How to calculate Cooks Distance, DFFITS using python statsmodel

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I want to calculate `Cooks_d` and `DFFITS` in Python using statsmodel.

Here is my code in Python:

```
X = your_str_cleaned[param]
y = your_str_cleaned['Visitor']
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()
```

I tried using this for getting `Cooks Distance` and `DFFITS`:

```
import statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence as st_inf
st_inf.OLSInfluence.summary_frame(results)
```

But I am getting this error:

> 'OLSResults' object has no attribute 'results'.

Can someone help me find where I am going wrong?

Comment: As shown in the answer using `get_influence` is easier. In the case here the call argument is wrong. It should have results provided to OLSInfluence and not to summary, i.e. `st_inf.OLSInfluence(results).summary_frame()` should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I experience the same problem, so I had to find a way around. I don't have much experience, and this doesn't fix the root issue with `OLSInfluence`. But it gives you `summary_frame`.

I will use pandas dataframes as the source of the data. Even if you have it in other objects (like arrays) you can transform them into a dataframe with relative ease. To show how it works, I will import the Boston housing prices data set from `sklearn.datasets`:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

#imports dataset
boston = load_boston()

#generates DataFrame bos
bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)

#adds columns names to bos
bos.columns = boston.feature_names 

#adds column 'PRICE' to bos
bos['PRICE'] = boston.target
```

Now let us consider the relation between the column `'RM'` and the column `'PRICE'`, with `'RM'`as independent variable. For simplicity, let us consider simple OLS. Here comes the actual answer:

```
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

m = ols('PRICE ~ RM',bos).fit()
infl = m.get_influence()
sm_fr = infl.summary_frame()
```

`sm_fr` has the columns `cooks_d` and `dffits` that you look for.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. You can also directly get dffits and cook's distance by using this: (c,p) = m.dffits and (c,p) = m.cooks_distance respectively in your code. c contains the value and p is the p-value.